# How to select a data in mysql with 3 or more consecutive months and bonus > 0?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to select a data where agentID has a bonus for 3 or more consecutive months.

here is my progress so far.

```
if($stmt = $conn->query("SELECT agentID, bonus FROM sample_tbl where agentID = '61599' && bonus > 0")){

    $elligible = $stmt->num_rows;

    if($elligible >= 3){
        echo "You have received a bonus for 3 or more consecutive months!";
    }else{
        echo "You have not received a bonus for 3 or more consecutive months!";
    }
  }else{
  echo $connection->error;
  }
```

My code is working! but I want to add a filtering process where it can detect the months.

here is the photo of my table.

[image]

If I use the agentID 61599, it should say "I have not received a bonus..." since it has a 0 bonus on month '1', year '2022'. It is not consecutive or in sequence with the months anymore.

[image]

I tried looking for the query how to do it but failed. Please comment if you have any idea how to do it, thank you.

Comment: Order the records by `year` then `month` for a given `agentID`; loop through the `result-set` in PHP to see if they meet your condition[s].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT agentID, 
           SUM(bonus > 0) OVER (PARTITION BY agentID 
                                ORDER BY `year` * 12 + `month`
                                RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) flag
    FROM test
)
SELECT agentID
FROM cte
WHERE flag = 3;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ecbc15f6f2ac886adcde6eeee61925a7

Comment: I am sorry to ask but where is the location should I put the with cte as... function in my code?

Comment: I can't seem to make it work sir.

Comment: @Jadey Fiddle added - investigate.

Comment: tried the fiddle, the agentID result gets multiplied if they have more than 3 consecutive months of bonus > 0 sir

Comment: @Jadey Add DISTINCT...